# Bluetooth microphone for interviewing people

Tags: bluetooth, microphones

[I run a 'Humans of' Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/humansofnewtownwgtn/), which involves me interviewing people on the street and taking photos of them.

Till now I've been using a voice recording app on my phone to record the conversation.

The problem I've been having is that often with the traffic and other ambient noise, it's hard to make out the conversation when I playback the recording later.

I'm thinking that a bluetooth microphone might help solve this. Either by placing the microphone in their hand to be closer to them, or better targeted at their voice.

Requirements:

- Bluetooth so it is recorded on my phone.
- Cheap - I'm not looking to spend a lot of money. < $100
- Will effectively isolate the voice from background noise.

Any suggestions to how this could be incorporated into the interview flow would also be appreciated. I need to be still able to operate my camera, and I don't want a visually distracting microphone in the picture.

Comment: Are you sure it has to be Bluetooth? It might also be worth considering a wired mic plugged into the headphone jack (I use one that's a lapel mic plugged into a headset splitter with my headphones for Skype calls and other stuff). I'm not sure how professional you need it to be. Also, a good mic like a Blue Snowball plugged into a laptop *would* work, but that might not be a good setup for you.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto Yeah it kinda does need to be bluetooth as I take the photos with my phone and a cable will be a pain

Answer (score 2):

There are not many good bluetooth options available, but I've listed out a couple of the best

***Nolan MIC Bluetooth Wireless Microphone - 64$***

- Bluetooth connectivity
- Range - 100ft(30m)
- Battery life - 6hr(moderate usage)
- Good customer reviews

If you can slightly bump up your price barrier then,

***Sony ECMAW4 Wireless Microphone - 150$*** (can get it for a lot cheaper offline)

- better audio quality
- can pair with other devices like camcorders
- can't pair with phones directly
- great customer reviews
- avg. battery
- Range - 164ft (Sony's claim)

Do check all the customer reviews of both the products on amazon and there is also a video about the latter product on its review page.

[Nolan MIC - amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009DT424Y)
[Sony MIC - amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JWU6WWO)

Comment: That first microphone you posted has pretty bad reviews.

Comment: yea but then these were the only options under the price tag